# MS Word 2016 Turn Off Formatting Marks

Tags: ms-office

I'm no longer able to control the visibility of formatting marks in MS Word documents using the "paragraph" button on the top menu/ribbon.  I'm unable to locate an override setting that specifies to always display formatting marks.  Is anyone familiar with how to remedy this issue?

[image]

Comment: Screenshot please?

Comment: Have a look at: [Show or hide formatting marks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-or-hide-formatting-marks-c2d8a607-5646-4165-8b08-bd68f9d172a0)

Comment: Screenshot added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Preferences** → **View** and disable **Paragraph marks**. This option, when enabled, overrides the button on the ribbon. Disable it to control the marks using the ribbon button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying Step 2 of [these troubleshooting steps](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Troubleshoot-Office-2011-for-Mac-issues-by-completely-uninstalling-before-you-reinstall-ba8d8d13-0015-4eea-b60b-7719c2cedd17). Basically my guess is you have a corrupted preference file. By removing your preferences files hopefully it resolves your issue.

If that doesn't work, following *all* those steps will completely remove it. I'd recommend that as a second solution.

EDIT: Original poster specified Office 2016. Same basic answer applies, however the instructions are [here instead](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-for-Mac-eefa1199-5b58-43af-8a3d-b73dc1a8cae3).

Comment: Thanks, but that article appears to be specific to Office 2011 for Mac.  I'm using Office 2016 (per the OP).

Comment: Same troubleshooting steps apply, @AJ, see my updated answer.

Comment: OK so basically the solution is:  uninstall, reinstall?  I guess I'll live with the formatting marks.

Comment: Removing your preferences files is relatively low-touch. No need to completely uninstall unless that doesn't work.

Comment: I tried removing the Word-specific plist files and that didn't fix the issue.  I'm not comfortable removing any of the other ones not knowing why, not to mention that some of them (e.g. outlook) are managed by my IT department.  I'd likely end up blowing away server/account settings, etc.  I agree that this is less invasive that uninstalling applications, but it still feels like a drastic approach to a minor issue.  Minor enough that I'll keep living with it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the individual marks are listed as "always shown" under Word options→Display→Always show these formatting marks on the screen.

(This is where the option is located in WinWord; hopefully the Apple equivalent is not so different)

Comment: [I can't find Display in Word preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0st9K.png), do you mean somewhere else or is it just different in macOS?